# How can I add a tradingview chart or its snapshot in google sheets using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, binance, tradingview-api

I used google apps script to fetch data from Binance, then drew candle stick charts in google sheet automatically. The quality of chart is not enough satisfactory. Please someone say how can I insert tradingview charts/snapshots in google sheets by means of google apps script.

I thank you very much for soonest answer.

Best Regards
Javad